# Understanding the Rune Knight Fighter's 15th level feature

Tags: dnd-5e, fighter, rune-knight

In the description for this feature, it says

> Master of Runes:
> You can invoke each rune you know from your Rune Carver feature twice, rather than once, and you regain all expended uses when you finish a short or long rest.

The first half is obvious, but what is the latter half referring to? All the runes with triggerable features already recharge on a short or long rest.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The second part is clarifying how much you recover during a rest. Without that clarification a player might believe that a short or long rest only recovers one use of the rune instead of two so that you'd need to rest twice to recover both uses.

Answer (score 5):

Until 14th level, each of a Rune Knight's runes can be activated once per short or long rest. Each rune ends with the following sentence:

> Once you invoke this rune, you can't do so again until you finish a short or long rest.

With the 15th level feature, each of their runes can be activated (up to) twice per short or long rest. This upgrade effectively doubles the character's uses of their runes.